# Struct defined in header not reconized in C file?

Tags: c, struct, header, include, definition

I am organizing my code so that and wanted to move some structure definitions to a header file then use them to declare variables in a separate c file (not main).

Header file:

```
#ifdef _InitSettingsGuard
#define _InitSettingsGuard

//Structure For Fault Levels
    typedef struct FaultLevel{
    FaultDef ThreePointThreeAux;
    FaultDef Twelve;
    FaultDef Five;
    FaultDef ThreePointThree;
    FaultDef PlusTwelveAux;
    FaultDef NegTwelveAux;
}FaultLevel;

typedef struct FaultLevel{
    FaultDef Test1;
    FaultDef Test2;
    FaultDef Test3;
}FaultLevel;

#endif
```

And here is my c file which I declare the variables:

```
#include "InitialSettings.h"

FaultLevel OneFaultLevel;
FaultLevel TwoFaultLevel;
FaultLevel ThreeLevel;
```

When i try to compile I am getting an error "unknown type name 'FaultLevel'"  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should change `#ifdef` to `#ifndef`.

Comment: This was the answer i forgot the n

Comment: Welcome to programming, where simple typos can hide for hours, days, or even weeks.  Then you show your code to someone else who sees the typo in three seconds....

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
#ifdef _InitSettingsGuard
#define _InitSettingsGuard
```

is wrong, the logic is inverted. You meant

```
#if !defined _InitSettingsGuard
```

or the commonly used short form

```
#ifndef _InitSettingsGuard
```

The point is to read the rest of the header if the guard symbol is *not* defined.

Also: there is no type called `FaultLevel` declared in the header. There is only `FaultDef`, so either change the usage:

```
FaultDef OneFaultLevel;
```

and so on, or change the `typedef`:ed name, of course. Make up your mind. :)